# Automerge: How can I reproduce this error change's deps should already be in the document

Tags: automerge

I had 3 people on the websocket changing the document (Automerge).
Somehow the document becomes unusable because of this error

`change's deps should already be in the document`

The code error I found is this link: https://automerge.org/automerge/src/automerge/error.rs.html#54

Which doesn't tell me what it means. Can someone explain what happened to this document?